# Diffing a file (not whole branch) in GIT with remote

Tags: git, diff, git-remote

ALL,

```
Igors-MacBook-Air:dbhandler igorkorot$ git diff foo/bar.cpp origin/master:foo/bar.cpp 
fatal: origin/master:foo/bar.cpp: no such path in the working tree.
Use 'git <command> -- <path>...' to specify paths that do not exist locally.
Igors-MacBook-Air:dbhandler igorkorot$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler.git (push)
```

Of course both files do exists - in both local and remote repository.

What am I doing wrong?

TIA!!

Comment: Just in case: and you have fetched the remote (because it's a new file?). Just thinking of easy explanations.

Comment: Try saying it this way: `git diff origin/master -- foo/bar.cpp`

Comment: @eftshift0, no I didn't fetch and its not the new file.

Comment: matt's comment is a comment (not an answer) but you can upvote comments. :-) Mine is an answer and is a little more complete as it mentions the `-R` you need here.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

You want:

```
git diff -R origin/master -- foo/bar.cpp
```

#### Longer

The syntax for `git diff` (as defined by the **SYNOPSIS** lines in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)) includes this form:

```
git diff [<options>] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
```

but not:

```
git diff [<options>] <path> <commit>:<path>
```

so:

> ```
> git diff foo/bar.cpp origin/master:foo/bar.cpp
> ```

is simply not acceptable as a set of command line arguments.

There's no *direct* way to compare just one on-disk file, such as `foo/bar.cpp`, to a committed file.  There is, however, a way to compare the *current commit* or *any other commit* to the *entire current working tree*.  For this you need:

```
git diff [<options>] <commit>
```

which fits within the *first* **SYNOPSIS** line.<sup>1</sup>  To this, you can—as suggested by that same line—add `-- foo/bar.cpp` to *limit the diff output* to just the one named file.

There's one flaw here and that is that the *order of the diff output* has the named *`commit`*'s copy of the file on the left, and the working-tree copy of the file on the right.  This is the reverse of what you would like.  If we were comparing two *`commit`*s we could just swap the order—that is, if we were doing `git diff a123456 b789abc -- foo/bar.cpp` we could just run `git diff b789abc a123456` instead—but here we can't do that.  Fortunately, one of the available *`options`* is `-R` (uppercase), meaning *reverse:* swap the left and right sides of the diff.

While this implicitly diffs the *entire commit* against the *entire working tree* (and then limits the displayed results to the one file if it's different), Git optimizes the operation internally.

---

<sup>1</sup>In a **SYNOPSIS** line, square brackets `[...]` indicate something optional and angle brackets `<...>` indicate that something is required here but you must supply it.  So `[<options>]` indicate that the options are optional and come from the set of options described later in the document, while `[--]` is an optional literal `--` and `<path>` is an optional path name.  The three dots `...` after `<path>` indicate that it can be repeated, in case you want to show more than one diff for the selected commit.

The purpose of the `--` here, which is optional but which I included, is to make sure that no *`path`* argument gets misinterpreted as a commit specifier (perhaps you have a branch named `foo/bar.cpp` for instance: that's a legal branch name!) or an option.  The latter wouldn't happen anyway, since options start with `-` and `foo` does not start with `-`, but using the double hyphen is a good habit to establish in case you find yourself with a file named `-f` or `-R` or whatever.